# Strange behavior of regexp in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I wrote a simple JavaScript function to split a file name into parts: given a file name of the type 'image01.png' it splits it into 'image', '01', 'png'.

For this I use the following regular expression:

```
var reg = /(\D+)(\d+).(\S+)$/;
```

This works.

However, I would like to be able to split also something like this: day12Image01.png into 'day12Image', '01', 'png'. Generally, I would like to have any number of additional digits associated to the body as long as they do not fall right before the extension.

I tried with:

```
var reg = /(.+)(\d+).(\S+)$/;
```

or the alternative:

```
var reg = /(\S+)(\d+).(\S+)$/;
```

Confusingly (to me), if I apply those regular expressions to 'image01.png' I get following decomposition: 'image0', '1', 'png'.

Why is the '0' being assigned to the body instead of the numerical index in these cases?

Thanks for any feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one possible regular expression that should work fine:

```
/^(.+?)(\d+)\.(\S+)$/
```

Note, you should escape a dot `.` character, since otherwise the regex will consider it as ['any character'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-dot) (so called ***"Special dot"***).

Comment: Indeed it works. Thanks also for the heads up on the special dot.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use non-greedy regular expression /(\S+?)(\d+).(\S+)$/. As far as I know this should work for javascript.

Comment: To be exact, this is *greedy*, or even more exact, **lazy** match.

Answer (score 0):

By default, capture groups are greedy, they will capture as much as they can, and since `+` means one OR more, it can just match the last digit and leave the first to the `.` or the `\S`. Make them un-greedy with `?`:

```
var reg = /(.+?)(\d+).(\S+)$/;
```

Or

```
var reg = /(\S+?)(\d+).(\S+)$/;
```